# what is adjust pure negative in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

My dsl query looks like below.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [{
        "terms": {
          "field": {...}
        }],
        "adjust_pure_negative": "false";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I change the flag **adjust_pure_negative** to true, I get no records and true is the default value.

Comment: this might help: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-does-adjust-pure-negative-flag-do/92348

Comment: when calling Lucene when all clauses are "must_not" clauses (no shoulds or musts). Ordinarily Lucene expects some positive clauses so would return nothing. Elasticsearch adjusts for this case by adding a must match_all type clause which means Lucene would then provide results, filtered by the must_nots.
But I do not have any must_nots in my query.

Comment: I'm surprised that you have to specify `adjust_pure_negative` at all. What happens if you simply remove `adjust_pure_negative`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why you get no records when you change the flag "adjust_pure_negative" to true, But when your elastic search query has only a "must-not" clause in it, and "adjust_pure_negative" is set as false. Then the elastic search will consider that you want to match absolutely nothing [as nothing is there to find similarity for]. As a result, the query will return no result for "must-not" clause. So to overcome this we set "adjust_pure_negative" as true.

This is kind of absurd. Therefore in the later version, this flag was removed and hard-coded as true.

Comment: which version do you mean by "later version"? I found a relevant issue [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/49530). **The flag is not removed** according the issue..

Answer (score 0):

when the query contains all "must_not" clause in it, then to get the query results, `adjust_pure_negative` need be sent as true,

```
GET /sample_index/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "modifiedTime": {
                          "from": 1690186437282,
                          "to": null
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "modifiedTime": {
                          "from": null,
                          "to": 1690186437283
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": false
    }
  }
}
```

This query will result 0 hits, meanwhile the data is present in index.
When set `"adjust_pure_negative": true` it will return the hits.

Elastic Lucene expects some positive clause in query, if there is no positive clause in the query, Elasticsearch take this flag and add a must `match_all` clause.

Source : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-does-adjust-pure-negative-flag-do/92348